# UILabel not showing correct data because it is nil

Tags: objective-c, ios4, uilabel, int

I have a uilabel, and it is not displaying the correct text because it is nil. How can I stop the label from being nil? Thanks
MKDev

```
- (IBAction)tapped
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:kTimerOn] == NO) {
        originalCountdownTime = 10;
        countdownTime = originalCountdownTime;
        [timeLeft setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", countdownTime]];
        countdownTimer = [[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(countDownOneSecond) userInfo:nil repeats:YES] retain];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:kTimerOn];
    }
    [self setTapAmount:tapAmount];
}



- (void)setTapAmount:(UILabel *)label
{
    ++numberOfTaps;
    NSString *countString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", numberOfTaps];
    [label setText:countString];
    NSLog(@"%@", countString);
}
- (void)countDownOneSecond
{
    int newTime = --countdownTime;
    timeLeft.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];
    if (countdownTime == 0)
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Congratulations" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"You Tapped %i times in %i seconds!", numberOfTaps, originalCountdownTime] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:@"Try Again", @"View Local Leaderboard",nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:NO forKey:kTimerOn];
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

Comment: "How can I stop the label from being nil?" has to be the best question I saw today!

Comment: I edited your question to format your code properly. Unlike other sites, you don't wrap your code in <code> tags here. This site recognizes text blocks inset by four spaces on the left as code blocks. There's a "code" button on the editor to set a selected range of text as code in one shot.

Answer (score 0):

That's poorly asked question, and ever more poorly formatted code, but I'm going to hazard the guess that you have not properly connected the UILabel outlet in your nib file.

Also, your IBAction "tapped" has the wrong signature.

Comment: It is perfectly connected in IB. What do you mean it has the wrong signature?

Comment: It should be `- (IBAction)tapped:(id)sender`, not `- (IBAction)tapped`.